# Show that λ defined as λ(E)=μ(A∩E) is a measure on Ω for E in Ω

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Let μ be a measure in Ω and A be afixed set in Ω .Then show that λ defined as λ(E)=μ(A∩E) is a measure on Ω for E in Ω.
How to prove this?

Comment: By proving that $\lambda$ has the characteristic properties of a measure. I reckon you are familiar with them. If not then find them e.g. by googling.

Comment: How to prove that..plz explain

Comment: $\lambda(E)=\mu(A\cap E)\geq0$ for instance. A [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Definition) takes nonnegative values. What is your problem? Can you prove that $\lambda(\varnothing)=0$ and $\lambda(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (E_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda(E_n)$ if the $E_i$ are disjoint? Then you are ready.

Comment: You must prove that $\lambda$ is a measure. By fixed $A$,$E$ $\mu(A\cap E)$ is just some element of $[0,\infty]$.

Answer (score 0):

Let it be that $\mu$ is a [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Definition) on [measurable space](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/measurable+space#definitions) $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$.

That means that $\mu$ is a function on $\mathcal A$ with specific properties (see the link).

Now for some fixed $A$ we prescribe the function $\lambda$ on $\mathcal A$ by $E\mapsto\mu(A\cap E)$.

To be shown is that also $\lambda$ has the characteristic properties that you can find in the link.

One of them is that $\lambda(\varnothing)=0$.

This follows from $\lambda(\varnothing)=\mu(A\cap\varnothing)=\mu(\varnothing)=0$.

I leave the rest to you.

Comment: Examine the following sequences for convergence if convergent,derive the limit. (1)An=[-1-(1/n),1-(1/2n)] (2)A2n=(0,1/2n). , A2n+1=(-1,1/2n+1)

Comment: There is no connection at all between your comment and my answer to your question.